# How to detect SQL injection in Java

Tags: java, sql-injection

I have classifier programmed by Java to detect and prevent SQL injection,the classifier works by pass by sentence "between two double quotations" from dataset to determine which the request is SQL injection or no.I need to convert this application to web based, so when user type for example 3 or 2=2 the application must read this sentence from URL rather than from my application as I said (sentence "between two double quotations")

For example:

```
String examplesql = "1' or 1=1";
String outputsql = nb.predict(examplesql);
System.out.format("The Traffic \"%s\" was classified as \"%s\".%n", examplesql, outputsql);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `PreparedStatement` class rather than doing manual checking. This means that the driver will automatically escape the string you give it and a SQL injection attempt will fail and whatever data they provide will be passed into the database field. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html for more details on how to use it.

To get a parameter that has been sent you can use

```
// create connection
String passed = request.getParameter("data");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES (?)");
statement.setString(1, passed);
statement.executeQuery();
```